# Making a little angular resolution calculator in JS but it returns NaN

Tags: javascript, logic, calculator, trigonometry

So, I'm in an astronomy class, and don't have a scientific calculator yet, so as a side project practice sometimes I'll translate a math question that would otherwise be tedious into a JS program so it can do physics math for me (like, last week i made an escape velocity function rather than punching in math individually to calculate escape velocity for multiple objects).

This new question basically states that Arcsine of theta = lightspeed/diameter of observation point (this is the equation the prof offered, though he said for the sake of simplicity we can use 1.00 rather than 1.22 in this measure as it is more precisely known).
I've designed a function to take diameter as a parameter and return the answer, but when I run it it just consoles NaN, I wonder if it's my logic or syntax that is faulting me or just poor math. I'm pretty rusty, but enjoy doing little side practices to probe into my comprehension of math equations and whatnot. If anyone felt like pointing out where I went wrong, it would help me diagnose what aspect of this process I am not retaining. I'm also like 4 drinks in and it's 1:30am tho lol this I guess is how I choose to spend my time. here goes:

```
let lightspeed = 3*Math.pow(10,8);

function Aungular (diameter){
    let ans1 =lightspeed/diameter;
    let ans =Math.asin(ans1);

    console.log(ans);
}

Aungular(20); // returns NaN
```

What am I messing up?
Oh, also I have like no trig experience haha, so it's important that I diagnose early on if this is what's causing whatever I overlooked.

(I hope that this doesn't cross any boundaries -- no coding is relevant to the assignment - this is something I'm doing on my own time as a brain exercise to increase my depth of understanding for math problems and exercise practice for writing code more fluently).

Edit: I mixed placements for diameter and lightspeed, program runs if they are switched. Solved, I guess. It's always the simplest stuff that I miss haha

Comment: From the [MDN documentation]: `The Math.asin() method returns a numeric value between -π/2 and π/2 radians for x between -1 and 1. If the value of x is outside this range, it returns NaN.` It would stand to reason that the value is out of that range.

Comment: Yeah, a [sine graph](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a2/Sine.svg) has a range from 1 to -1  (inclusive) - that's the range of numbers it can output (ie: `y`). [asin/arcsin](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Arcsine.svg) is the inverse of sin, so its input (`x`) needs to be between -1 and 1 (inclusive). In your example `lightspeed/diameter` gives `15000000`, which isn't between -1 and 1

Comment: Oh! I see what you mean, I think. So Math.asin(x); doesn't equal sin^-1(x) as one would input it into a calculator, then. I feel stumped for how to translate this equation because it's just registering in my brain that there's some sort of unit conversion that i'm overlooking. That makes sense that it wouldn't accept 20 as a parameter. F I wish I was smarter lol

Comment: OH it's diameter/lightspeed not lightspeed/diameter haha wow duh. Also props to me for spelling Angular as "Aungular" both in naming and calling this so it still attempted to run hahaha . It works now, I'll get it looked over to make sure I'm doing it proper but I would hella rather do this for telescope calculations/predictions rather than several steps each time. Thank u guys !